# Is it possible to show the current file I have open in vim in my screen tabs?

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

Was wondering if it'd be possible to somehow show the current file I'm editing in the tabs of my screen

[image]

Because it'd be way easier to know what I'm switching between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this (indirectly) in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
let &titlestring = "Editing: " . expand("%:p")
if &term == "screen"
  set t_ts=^[k
  set t_fs=^[\
endif
if &term == "screen" || &term == "xterm"
  set title
endif
```

It changes my terminal tab, and I assume from reading it (and the `screen(1)` man page) that it should work with screen as well.

Comment: That seemed to just add the current filename at the bottom row when I'm viewing the file, but not specifically in the screen tabs themselves.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work either (nor anything listed [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Automatically_set_screen_title)). cychoi's answer worked for me, though. To any readers, also be mindful not to copy-paste the `^[` character (it's special and cannot be copied directly). A better alternative is to use `<Esc>` as in: `set t_ts="\<Esc>k"`. Also check your `$TERM` variable because this solution only works if your term is set to `screen` (mine is set to `screen.xterm-256color`, so I had to change the conditional). See cychoi's answer for a more flexible version if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this to change both the xterm's (or sisters and brothers such as PuTTY) window title and GNU screen's window title.

Put in your `vimrc`:

```
if has('title')
  if &term =~# '\v^(screen|xterm|putty).*'
    set title
  endif

  if &title
    " xterm OSC for changing window title and icon name
    let &t_ts="\<Esc>]0;"
    let &t_fs="\<C-G>"

    " if inside GNU screen, change screen's window title and 
    " xterm's window title on BufEnter event
    if $STY
      augroup cy.title
        autocmd!
        autocmd BufEnter * let &t_ts="\<Esc>k" . expand('%:t') . "\<Esc>\\\<Esc>]0;"
      augroup END
    endif
  endif
endif
```